# How to resize images in org-mode

Tags: html, image, resize, export, org-mode

Is there a general way to define the size, in percent or pixels, for an image that is linked in `org-mode`?

Say I have the following link in my `.org` file:

```
[[~/images/example.jpg]]
```

This JPG is way too large, so if I export it to HTML or LaTeX or open it in `org-mode` with <kbd>C-c C-o i</kbd> will only see a fraction of the image.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

As of [Org 8.0](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/), "Attribute lines now take [plists](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-8.0.html#sec-8-3)" :

```
#+attr_html: :width 100px
#+attr_latex: :width 100px
[[~/images/example.jpg]]
```

Answer (score 65):

As per Jacobo's comment, add the following to your init.el file:

```
(setq org-image-actual-width nil)
```

Then in org-mode, you can precede each JPG, PNG, and SVG  as shown in the following example to adjust the size of each inlined image.

```
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 100
[[~/images/example.svg]]
```

If you want to size this for both inline previews and html output:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: width="100px"
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 100
[[~/images/example.svg]]
```

Comment: Adam, I would assume that Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) images do not have an inherent size, as they are designed to be scalable.

Comment: Hi @NiclasBörlin it looks like this was a bug in my version of Emacs (but has since been resolved). I can confirm that as of Emacs 27.2 (Railwaycat Homebrew edition of Mitsuharu's Emacs) this works for SVGs as well.

Comment: @Adam I accidentally down-voted your answer, and stack overflow does not permit me to adjust it. Due to that I upvoted your comment. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @KadirGunel No worries, I'm now only 38 points behind the accepted answer! ;D

Comment: How about height?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein the height should adjust itself proportionately, when you set the width. So as long as your are not looking to purposefully distort your image, you only need to set one of these.

Comment: I want to purposefully "distort" my image because by default the data points look too clustered, so I'd like to have a different ratio. Thanks.

Comment: instead of `org-image-actual-width` variable you can use `‘ORG-IMAGE-ACTUAL-WIDTH` property, when set to `t` use the actual image size, when set to `nil` use your `#ATTR-*` value, when set to a number say `300` use it for all images, ignoring an `#ATTR-*`, when set to a list like `(300)`, use the  `#ATTR-*` when present otherwise use `300`.

Answer (score 14):

```
#+ATTR_HTML: width="100px"
[[~/images/example.jpg]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer bzg!

First of all, I was hoping for an option that is not specific to html but would also work for LaTex and viewing in Emacs itself.

Anyway, even though your suggestion appears to be correct according to the official documentation [1][2] it does somehow not work for me.

I'm using emacs 24.1.1 without any customization but when I try your code, the image is still in its original, gigantic size. 
This is true for Chrome and Firefox.


[1] http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/images-and-xhtml-export.html
[2] http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: I've also tried 

    #+ATTR_HTML: width="0.3"

Which, if I understand correct, should scale by a factor of 0.3 (or 0.003 = 0.3% ?) but this has no effect either. :-/

Comment: In order for this to work, you need to set this in your .emacs file: `(setq org-image-actual-width nil)`. [Other possible values and behaviours are explained](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-08/msg01388.html) in this post to org-mode's mailing list

Answer (score 14):

This is a sample on how to resize an image using percentages *(Org mode version 9.0.5)*:

```
#+CAPTION: Weight space                                                                                                                                     
#+ATTR_HTML: :alt neural network :title Neural network representation :align right                                                                          
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 50% :height 50%                                                                                                                         
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzHSl.jpg
```

Comment: other answers didn't work for me for images based on a URL

Comment: Does this work with inline previews as well?

Comment: @HappyFace yes it does

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way to resize images in emacs Org mode for preview (not exporting).  Typically,

1. We want to set an image to a specific width like 249px when we need to.
2. We want to set a default image width, so that we don't need to specify `+attr_html` for every image - that would be tedious.

This can be achieved by configuring `org-image-actual-width` like follows:

```
(setq org-image-actual-width (list 550))
```

Then, in your `.org` file, if you have

```
#+attr_html :width 249
[[~/images/example1.jpg]]
```

then the image will be displayed in preview at width 249px. For another image, where no `+attr_*` is specified, the default width of 550px will be applied.

```
[[~/images/example2.jpg]]
```

You can see this behavior from the documentation in [org-mode source code](https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/blob/5832c8fc9326f495a898c9ac518b1fbf943882e5/lisp/org.el#L15453):

```
When set to a number in a list, try to get the width from any
#+ATTR.* keyword if it matches a width specification like
  #+ATTR_HTML: :width 300px
and fall back on that number if none is found.
```

I found it hard to understand what does "a number in a list mean", so I looked at [the implementation](https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/blob/5832c8fc9326f495a898c9ac518b1fbf943882e5/lisp/org.el#L16681), and indeed, something like `(list 550)` works.

Answer (score 3):

For LaTeX, to remove the default `width=.9\linewidth`, set the `org-latex-image-default-width` to empty string. By this way, the image will have its natural size.

To do that on the fly use the `set-variable` emacs command. Or to set this variable permanently, add the following line in your init.el :
`(setq org-latex-image-default-width "")`

Comment: and to set it to the full linewidth (or any other value), use `(setq org-latex-image-default-width "1.0\\linewidth")`

Answer (score 0):

For export to LaTeX, if you hope to 'scale' the image (a la Alioth's response for HTML), there are a few ways to go.

Scaling relative to the image size:

`#+ATTR_LATEX: :scale 1.2`

Scaling relative to what LaTeX thinks is going on with the typesetting:

`#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.40\linewidth`

`#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.5\textwidth`