# How to make inline images responsive in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I toggle inline image using `org-toggle-inline-images` which shows the image(s). However, when the image it too large it will overflow the editor's frame (See screenshot below).

[image]

How to make the image responsive which means the max size of the image should never exceed the width of window size.

Of course, I can use the code below to fix the size of the image. But what I truly want is some kind of responsive image displaying.

```
(setq org-mode-actual-width 600)
```

[image]

Thanks for your time viewing this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of `org-image-actual-width`:

```
Documentation:
Should we use the actual width of images when inlining them?

When set to t, always use the image width.

When set to a number, use imagemagick (when available) to set
the image's width to this value.

When set to a number in a list, try to get the width from any
#+ATTR.* keyword if it matches a width specification like

  #+ATTR_HTML: :width 300px

and fall back on that number if none is found.

When set to nil, try to get the width from an #+ATTR.* keyword
and fall back on the original width if none is found.
```

So you could use the attribute #+ATTR_HTML to specify the width.  It has to be specified manually though.  Is this responsive enough?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69339844/2893053 for an example usage when `org-image-actual-width` is set to "a number in a list"

Answer (score 6):

The function below re-renders the org-mode inline images whenever the window is resized by using hooks. It shrinks the image only when the window is displaying less than 80 columns (usually 1/3 of the screen). I believe it works better than always rendering in window width.

```
(defun org-image-resize (frame)
  (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
      (if (< (window-total-width) 80)
      (setq org-image-actual-width (window-pixel-width))
    (setq org-image-actual-width (* 80 (window-font-width))))
      (org-redisplay-inline-images)))

(add-hook 'window-size-change-functions 'org-image-resize)
```

[GIF Demo of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gilcz.gif)

If you want the image just matching the size of your window width:

```
(defun org-image-resize (frame)
  (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
      (setq org-image-actual-width (window-pixel-width))
      (org-redisplay-inline-images)))

(add-hook 'window-size-change-functions 'org-image-resize)
```

Or change the `(window-pixel-width)` into `(- (window-pixel-width) 20)` if you want some margin on the right side.