# Github org-mode html export image resizing

Tags: html, github, image-resizing, org-mode

[How to resize images in org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670654/how-to-resize-images-in-org-mode) describes to resize images using `#:ATTR_HTML`. This has not worked for GitHub's org-mode export, though: adding

```
#:ATTR_HTML: :width 100px
```

works in emacs' export, but GitHub [seems to omit it](https://github.com/serv-inc/franklin/blob/master/README.org).

Is there any way to make GitHub resize an org-exported image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of its [rendering pipeline](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup), after converting Org to HTML,

> The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, inline-styles, and `class` or `id` attributes.

The sanitation rules used to be referenced here as well, but this reference [was removed in October, 2018](https://github.com/github/markup/commit/56a58500418779ee3e06db2bfcd86654acbf2ce7). As a result it is no longer clear which tags and attributes are permitted, but it is very likely that the generated `width="100px"` attribute is removed during this process.

It is also possible that [the Ruby library GitHub users to convert Org to HTML](https://github.com/wallyqs/org-ruby) simply doesn't support `ATTR_HTML`.

In either case, your best bet is probably to use a real 100px-wide version of that image.