# How to resize images in org2html?

Tags: html, image, org-mode

Adding `#+attr_html: :width 100px` above aa image link changes the width of the image in the exported html file. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670654/how-to-resize-images-in-org-mode) for more info.

However, I wish I can set all images' widths to `100px` in the exported html file without specifying `#+attr_html: :width 100px` **for each image** -- it's too much work. For some exceptions, I wish if `#+attr_html: :width 200px` is added, then the method should respect it.

If all I care is about the widths of images **within** org-mode, then this [post](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-08/msg01388.html) suffices by adding `(setq org-image-actual-width '(400))` to the config file. However, that does not take care of the images widths in the exported html file.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that globally (and looking at the code seems to confirm that you cannot, although I might have missed something). OTOH, it's hardly "too much work": you can do a search-and-replace with one command essentially, for the existing cases. For new cases, you can define a command to insert the attribute line and bind the command to a key.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the strategy presented in [Alignment of images in HTML export](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41534/alignment-of-images-in-html-export) could be adopted here to "override the style used for images by adding custom CSS at the beginning of your document":

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style> .figure p {width="200";}</style>
```

Comment: I will try it when I get back home. I hope it respects ad hoc attribute setting.

Comment: any luck, @student?